# c++ program not running on visual

Tags: c++

everything else runs except the linear search.. when i run it, it says i'm missing something here ( **error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'**>>> `int result=linearsearch(lego,15,val);`

```
#include<stdio.h>

void display(int[] ,int );
float average(int[], int );
int linearsearch (int lego[], int b, int val);

int main() // main() must return int
{
    float avg;
    int val;

    int lego[15]= {2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30};
    char muzik[20]= {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t'};
    float blu[10]= {1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2.0,2.1}; // float values not chars

    display(lego,15);

    average(lego,15);
    avg=average(lego,15);
    printf("Average = %.2f\n",avg); // added newline

    printf("Please enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &val);
    int result=linearsearch(lego,15,val);
    if(result>=0) {
        printf("the number is : %d" ,lego[result]);
    } else {
        printf("You have entered a wrong number %d\n",val);
    }
}

void display(int lego[], int Se) {
    int w;

    for(w=0; w<Se; ++w) {
        printf("%d ",lego[w]);
    }
    printf("\n"); // added newline
}

float average(int lego[], int b) {
    int s, sum=0;
    float avg;

    for(s=0; s<b; ++s) {
        sum+=lego[s];
    }
    avg=(float)sum/b; // (float) cast forces floating-point division
    return avg;
}

int linearsearch (int lego[], int b, int val) {
    int i=0;

    for(i=0; i<b; ++i) {
        if(val==lego[i]) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Your code was edited for you this time. Don't expect that to be the case. Provide code blocks that you'd be proud of please.

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Comment: You haven't initialized your `int val` and then pass it to the function and use it in a comparison.  This is UB and may be giving you your error.  Some compilers autoinit variables, but some do not.

Comment: @Chemistpp:  `val` is set on the line just prior, in the `scanf` statement.  (Not foolproof, I know, but not the source of the problem)

Comment: Please choose a more descriptive title, and **provide a full description of the problem** in your question. At the moment the question is undecipherable.

Comment: still giving an error

Comment: @abelenky That's what I get for briefly scanning for `val = blah;`

Comment: I guess is this is not your actual code that is giving you the problem.  I can say if it is in that function, then either val is not input correctly or your integer `b` is going outside the bounds of your array (it's not in this exact example).  You have no error checking for them.

Comment: this is an assignment i got to do. its actually 12 questions and i'm currently at 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code compiles for me and when I run it, I get the expected behavior. What message are you seeing?

**EDIT**

Okay I think I got it. You have C++ code and you are compiling it as C code. In C code, all variables must be declared at the beginning of the function. Either, change the extension to .cpp or move the declaration of result to the line just under val, and change it later:

```
float avg;
int val;
int result;

...

result = linearsearch (lego, 15, val)
```

Comment: this is the error i keep getting ->>  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'

Comment: Me too.  copy/pasted code, works perfect.